# Slow AsQueryable() and universal method for IQueryable and IEnumerable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

I want using one method for IQueryable and for IEnumerable:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereEx<T>(this IEnumerable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)
{
   return query.AsQueryable().Where(exp);
}

public static IEnumerable<Ship> GetShipsSome(this IEnumerable<Ship> query)
{
   return query.WhereEx(x => x.Id > 150);
}
```

Using:
With IQueryable:

```
var x = context.Set<Ships>().AsNoTracking().GetShipsSome(); //from DB
```

With IEnumerable:

```
var x = shipsInRam.GetShipsSome(); //from collection in ram(list)
```

But if i using `IEnumerable` (take from collection in ram), my code is slower than `IEnumerable.Where` becouse `AsQueryable()` convert collection. How can i optimize my code?

Fix: `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where`

Comment: Is the `query` an `IEnumerable` or an `IQueryable`?

Comment: query can be IEnumerable and IQueryable

Comment: And what did you pass in when you did the performance test?

Comment: `shipsInRam.AsQueryable().Where(exp);`
vs
`shipsInRam.Where(exp);`

Comment: I find it unlikely you're able to see a noticable difference between `query.Where(exp)` and `query.AsQueryable().Where(exp)`

Comment: Are you absolutely the `shipsInRam` is *actually* in memory? Can you try `shipsInRam.ToList().AsQueryable().Where(exp)` vs `shipsInRam.ToList().Where(exp)`?

Comment: becouse i can't pass expression to IEnumerable.Where
Expression.Compile is slower than AsQueryable()

Comment: shipsInRam it is simple `List<Ship>`

Comment: Can you show us your benchmark code showing the slowdown between the two? I am not convinced there is any noticeable difference, unless you're trying to trim nano seconds off your code.

Comment: http://savepic.ru/8118910.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading your claims, I was not convinced - so I wrote a benchmark test.

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000).ToList();

for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var warmupA = list.WhereEx(a => a > 500000).ToList();
    var warmupB = list.Where(a => a > 500000).ToList();;
    var warmupC = list.WhereExCompile(a => a > 500000).ToList();;
}

var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var wherexresult =  list.WhereEx(a => a > 500000).ToList();
}

sw.Stop();
var wherextime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var whereresult =  list.Where(a => a > 500000).ToList();
}

sw.Stop();
var whertime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var whereexcompileresult =  list.WhereExCompile(a => a < 500000).ToList();
}

sw.Stop();
var whereexcompiletime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

wherextime.Dump();
whertime.Dump();
whereexcompiletime.Dump();

public static class a  {
    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereExCompile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)
    {
        return query.AsQueryable().Where(exp);
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereEx<T>(this IEnumerable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)
    {
        return query.Where(exp.Compile());
    }
}
```

Which gives the results:

```
list.WhereEx(a => a > 500000) = 1320ms
list.Where(a => a > 500000) = 1572ms
list.WhereExCompile(a => a < 500000) = 1284ms
```

And with optimizations enabled:

```
list.WhereEx(a => a > 500000) = 1285ms
list.Where(a => a > 500000) = 1372ms
list.WhereExCompile(a => a < 500000) = 1263ms
```

The differences are negligible (this was running 100,000,000 times *each*, each taking less than 1.5seconds). If anything, your method is *faster* than `.Where()`. So where are you getting the idea that the code needs to be optimised?

Comment: try firstOrDefault instead of Where. And query with several properties.

Comment: @GLeBaTi `FirstOrDefault` works even *better* than the where. `WhereEx` and `WhereExCompile` are consistently 3-4x faster than `Where. I don't believe several properties would have any affect on the performance - though you're welcome to take the benchmark code and try it yourself.

Comment: somehow I got slower, but it's quite a short time. Apparently I need to reduce the number of calls. Thank you.

Comment: @GLeBaTi I took a look at your picture. I had a similar result with the benchmark, however it's not quite the same as what I tested. Can you try replacing `allAsteroids.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(...)` with `allAsteroids.AsQueryable().Where(...).FirstOrDefault()`? For me it's 2-3 faster this way. I'm stumped as to why, however.

Answer (score 1):

You should return `IQueryable<T>` and not `IEnumerable<T>` and if you are getting records just to show for your user, and will not change any of this records, for better performance, you can get your records using `AsNoTracking()`.

One more thing, you must use `AsQueryable()` likie this

`return query.Where(exp).AsQueryable();`